# How we can control the DC motor

Tags: microcontroller, motor, dc

I have an DME60B motor (DC) with 24V and 490 RPM.
I want to turn it on every 8 am Daily and to work for just 5 min.
if we want to change the dirction of the motor after 2.5 min to work reverse?
what I shoud use of electric parts and how ?
should I use timer or what?

In general, how can make a simple controler to conrtol this system?

Please, explain it as if you're talking to a 6-year old kid, I'm not knowledgeable in this field but I want to know the concept.

Comment: Timer??? What do you have? a MCU?

Comment: Does the solution have any size/power restrictions?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by a microcontroller driving two DPST relays.  One relay applies voltage to the motor to run it forwards, the other to run it in reverse.  The micro must leave enough time between turning off one relay and turning on the other to ensure break before make, else you blow a fuse.

As for timing, many micros are capable of driving common 32768 Hz watch crystals while sleeping and otherwise taking very little power.  The micro could wake up every 2 seconds and decide whether its time to run the motor or not.